# How to make a GET request for an api RESTful (application express)?

Tags: rest, oracle-apex

This is my first time creating an api restfull on apex (application express). I am using the emp table from oracle (https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_O5AEB2HE08PYEPTGCFLZU9YCV.html)

I have created an api restful following this guide (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/apex/r50/Restful%20Services/restful_services.html#overview)

NOTE : there is no longer that "test" button shown in the guide

This is the information I entered :

Name : serviceOne
URI Prefix : so
URI Template : employees
Method : GET
Format : JSON
query : select * from emp

I am using postman from chrome to test my api.

let's say that http://example.com/apex is my apex app

what should be the url in postman to make a GET request to the api rest I just created?

Comment: Are you using "/" at the end of URI Prefix and Template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a valid URL to a restful service from apex:

https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/stackquestions/hr/empinfo/

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/<WORKSPACENAME>/<URI PREFIX>/<URI TEMPLATE>/
```

Use this workspace to check something:

workspace: STACKQUESTIONS

user: test

password: test

login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550

Go to: SQL Workshop >> RESTFul Services >> oracle.examplehr >> empinfo/

click on image:
[image]

Comment: thanks, I still have errors 404 but at least, I have a clue on how to fix them now ^^